# XSLT sort by deep nodes

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Is it possible to sort by nodes that are many levels deeper than the current node?

I have an xml file I am turning in a html table that represents a product structure.
I would like to sort on the sct_cst_tot value in 'Part ERP CostSet' Item

I was not able to correct sort using  
I tried in the  and  but couldn't find the solution.

Sub items of TOP LEVEL ASSEMBLY would sort by sct_cst_tot

- 6340.70
- 7040.30

Sub items of NEXT LEVEL ASSEMBLY 1  would sort by sct_cst_tot

- 400.00
- 600.00

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Result>
    <Item type="Part">
        <name>TOP LEVEL ASSEMBLY</name>
        <item_number>TLA1</item_number>
        <Relationships>
            <Item type="Part ERP CostSet">
                <sct_cst_tot>14205.1513157895</sct_cst_tot>
            </Item>
            <Item type="Part BOM">
                <quantity>4</quantity>
                <related_id>
                    <Item type="Part">
                        <name>NEXT LEVEL ASSEMBLY 1</name>
                        <item_number>NLA1</item_number>
                        <Relationships>
                            <Item type="Part ERP CostSet">
                                <sct_cst_tot>7040.3000000000</sct_cst_tot>
                            </Item>
                            <Item type="Part BOM">
                                <quantity>1</quantity>
                                <related_id>
                                    <Item type="Part">
                                        <name>COMPONENT 2</name>
                                        <item_number>ICN-0002</item_number>
                                        <Relationships>
                                            <Item type="Part ERP CostSet">
                                                <sct_cst_tot>600.00</sct_cst_tot>
                                            </Item>
                                        </Relationships>
                                    </Item>
                                </related_id>
                            </Item>
                            <Item type="Part BOM">
                                <quantity>3</quantity>
                                <related_id>
                                    <Item type="Part">
                                        <name>COMPONENT 3</name>
                                        <item_number>ICN-0003</item_number>
                                        <Relationships>
                                            <Item type="Part ERP CostSet">
                                                <sct_cst_tot>400.0000000000</sct_cst_tot>
                                            </Item>
                                        </Relationships>
                                    </Item>
                                </related_id>
                            </Item>
                        </Relationships>
                    </Item>
                </related_id>
            </Item>
            <Item type="Part BOM">
                <quantity>2</quantity>
                <related_id>
                    <Item type="Part">
                        <name>NEXT LEVEL ASSEMBLY 2 </name>
                        <item_number>NLA2</item_number>
                        <Relationships>
                            <Item type="Part ERP CostSet">
                                <sct_cst_tot>6340.6999997988</sct_cst_tot>
                            </Item>
                        </Relationships>
                    </Item>
                </related_id>
            </Item>
        </Relationships>
    </Item>
    <BOM>10</BOM>
</Result>
```

Here is the xsl file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:aras="http://www.aras-corp.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table style="width: 98%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>Part Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Single Unit Cost</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <xsl:call-template name="Levels"></xsl:call-template>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Levels">
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Item[@type='Part']">
                <xsl:variable name="Depth" select="count(ancestor::Item[@type='Part'])"></xsl:variable>
                <tr>
                    <!--Method to visual show where the item sits in the BOM hierarchy-->
                    <xsl:call-template name="IndentLevel">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Depth" select="$Depth" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="item_number"></xsl:value-of>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"></xsl:value-of>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Depth" select="count(ancestor::Item[@type='Part'])"></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="IndentLevel">
        <xsl:param name="Depth" />
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=0">0</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=1">1</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=2">2</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=3">3</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=4">4</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=5">5</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=6">6</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$Depth=7">7</xsl:if>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part']">
        <xsl:param name="Depth"></xsl:param>
        <!--Quantity-->
        <td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <!--Top level Quantity is always 1-->
                <xsl:when test="$Depth = '0'">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../../quantity != '0'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../quantity"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot,&quot;###,###,##0.00&quot;)"></xsl:value-of>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the current output (Note the levels may not roll up correctly to the next value)

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|PartNumber |Name                   |Single Unit Cost   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|0| | | | | | | |TLA1       |TOP LEVEL ASSEMBLY     |14,205.15          |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| |1| | | | | | |NLA1       |NEXT LEVEL ASSEMBLY 1  |7,040.30           |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| | |2| | | | | |ICN-0002   |COMPONENT 2            |600.00             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| | |2| | | | | |ICN-0003   |COMPONENT 3            |400.00             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| |1| | | | | | |NLA2       |NEXT LEVEL ASSEMBLY 2  |6,340.70           |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Here is the desired output

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|PartNumber |Name                   |Single Unit Cost   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|0| | | | | | | |TLA1       |TOP LEVEL ASSEMBLY     |14,205.15          |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| |1| | | | | | |NLA2       |NEXT LEVEL ASSEMBLY 2  |6,340.70           |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| |1| | | | | | |NLA1       |NEXT LEVEL ASSEMBLY 1  |7,040.30           |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| | |2| | | | | |ICN-0003   |COMPONENT 3            |400.00             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| | |2| | | | | |ICN-0002   |COMPONENT 2            |600.00             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Edited to simplify the xml output

Comment: I suggest you minimize your example files - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

By minimize, I meant both your XML and your XSLT. Here's an example of XSLT that does nothing but sort the items by the `sct_cst_tot` value of one their descendants.

If I understand correctly, you need to multiply that value by a quantity, but I was unable to penetrate the logic by which the quantity is determined.

In any case, XSLT does not allow sorting by a variable - so if you want to sort by the extended cost AND show it in a table cell, you will need to calculate it twice.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Item[@type='Part']">
        <xsl:sort select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot" /></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

I am not sure if it's coincidence or not, but I have managed to get the requested order by adding the following two sort instructions to your "Levels" template:

```
<xsl:template name="Levels">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Item[@type='Part']">

        <!-- sort by depth -->
        <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::Item[@type='Part'])" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <!-- sort by cost -->
        <xsl:sort select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>

            <xsl:variable name="Depth" select="count(ancestor::Item[@type='Part'])"></xsl:variable>
            <tr>
            ....
```

---

### Edit 2:

> here is the relationship from the Part BOM
>   (related_id/Item[@type='Part']/Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP
>   CostSet']/sct_cst_tot). The Product (or Bill of Materials) structure
>   should always be maintained. I.e. in the example above, ICN-0002 and
>   ICN-0003 are the 'children' of NLA1, so should always be directly
>   under NLA1, just as NLA1 and NLA2 are the children of TLA1

If I understand this correctly, this is not (only) a matter of sorting, but rather of processing the nodes in their hierarchical order - with only **siblings** sorted among themselves by cost.

That means that you cannot do an indiscriminate:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Item[@type='Part']">
```

Instead, you must start at the top and tell each part to process its sub-parts in turn. Try the following skeleton stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Result">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Single Unit Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[@type='Part']">
                <xsl:sort select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </tbody>
     </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part']">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="item_number"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot" /></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part BOM']/related_id/Item[@type='Part']">
        <xsl:sort select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry my xslt wasn't very clear. I have simplified and removed some of the fields that were not relevant to the question. I am only trying to sort by the sct_cst_tot value. However I want to maintain the structure as shown in the desired output.

Comment: @Spacko I am afraid this is still not clear. What is the exact sort order in your expected output example? Clearly, the parts are **not** sorted **only** by sct_cst_tot value.

Comment: @Spacko ... unless I was lucky in my guess - see the edit to my post.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is not too good.          Each 'Part' element will have a relationship with 1 'Part ERP CostSet' Item element and 0 or more 'Part BOM' Item elements. Each Part BOM element will be related to 1 lower level 'Part' element (which starts the cycle until there are no more 'Part BOM' elements).  Basically I want the 'Part BOM' item elements to be sorted by the cost of their related part

Comment: here is the relationship from the Part BOM (related_id/Item[@type='Part']/Relationships/Item[@type='Part ERP CostSet']/sct_cst_tot). The Product (or Bill of Materials) structure should always be maintained. I.e. in the example above, ICN-0002 and ICN-0003 are the 'children' of NLA1, so should always be directly under NLA1, just as NLA1 and NLA2 are the children of TLA1.